# How to setup partitions in FreeNAS?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, security, raid, freenas

I am new to FreeNAS and watched a video on how to set it up, in which it has been running great. However, now I want to add cameras, which basically just run until you run out of space, but I don't want them to take up all the space, just limit them basically. I would do that by having a section dedicated to them.

So my FreeNAS system has 2x4TB NAS hard drives. I am running them in mirror. So I have a little less than 4TB of useable space basically. What I want to do is have 1.5TB of space for my IP cameras and then the remaining space to be general space for my other files/videos/whatever. I want to set it up so that in Windows, I will see 2 different network storages, one being camera storage and the other general storage.

I tried setting up a 2 zVol, but that didn't allow me to set up Windows sharing as Windows sharing on FreeNAS only sees datasets pool. I tried 2 datasets and that doesn't give me the option to specify how big the space to be. When I try to completely start over from scratch — yes I backed up what was previously on my NAS system — it doesn't give me an option to do this, just using mirror. Tthe only other thing was striping and striping is useless in my case because if my drive fails, well then I am screwed and completely defeats the purpose of why I build my NAS.

I don't want to have to go out and get 2x 2TB drives as I don't have the money. So can someone walk me through what to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to have create two datasets or however many "partitions" you want, so if you want 6 "partitions" then you make 6 datasets.

In my case, I want two, one for general storage and one for camera's storage. Then you need to make sure you have created all your users and set up windows permissions setting what user can use what partitions.

Then go back to your pool and go to a dataset/partition that you want to limit the amount of space on and click on the three dots and do not select edit ACL (access control list, for giving a user access to this) but just select the edit in general. Then go to advanced settings.

Then in the box for quota, you then put in how much space you want to give this dataset/partition, keep in mind you obviously cant go past how much storage you have in general on your FreeNAS.